# Can a web host stop pdo->prepare() from running?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've searched several answers on pdo->prepare() but none of those answers quite address the situation I'm experiencing.

I've just changed web hosts of a clients website to 1and1. What is working in development on my local machine is not working on 1and1 hosting servers. Yes, PDO is there, PHP Version 7.0 is installed and operational.

This is my DBClass

```
class DBClass {

    public static function dbConnect () {
        $host_name = "host";
        $database = "db";
        $user_name = "un";
        $password = "pw";
        try {
           return new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;", $user_name, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          return "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
          die();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my handler which generates all pages on this site.

```
$dbConn = DBClass::dbConnect();
echo "<h3>Standard PDO using dbh->query</h3>";
$stmt = $dbConn->query("SELECT * FROM vfs");
$recs = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($recs as $rec) {
    echo "id: " . $rec['id'] . ", parent: " . $rec['parent'] . ", url: " . $rec['url'] . ", short_url: " . $rec['short_url'] . " title: " . $rec['title']  . "<br />";
}
echo "<h3>Running dbh->prepare</h3>";
$pstmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM vfs WHERE url = :url || short_url = :url");
$pstmt->bindParam(':url', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$pstmt->execute();

$vfsCnt = $pstmt->rowCount();

if($pstmt->rowCount() == 1){
    $pgRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = ?");
    $pstmt->execute(array($pgRec['template_id']));
    if($pstmt->rowCount() == 1){
        $templateRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vfs WHERE url = '/404.php' || short_url = '/404.php'");
        $pstmt->execute();
        $pgRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = ?");
        $pstmt->execute(array($pgRec['template_id']));
        $templateRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
} else {
    $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vfs WHERE url = '/404.php' || short_url = '/404.php'");
    $pstmt->execute();
    $pgRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = ?");
    $pstmt->execute(array($pgRec['template_id']));
    $templateRec = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The top part of the code executes, pulling from dbo->query() while pdo->prepare() triggers the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /homepages/3/d692026076/htdocs/aeallord.com/public/cms.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/3/d692026076/htdocs/aeallord.com/public/cms.php on line 28

I don't understand why pdo->prepare() would trigger and error such as this when pdo->query() runs showing the database connection is made, it can be queried against but the pdo->prepare() causes a failure.

Results of the above code can be seen at aeallord.com

Any guidance on my code error or if there is some way 1and1 could be stopping pdo->prepare() from executing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to edit my question, but I've updated the code on aeallord.com to state $dbConn->prepare() from $dbh->prepare. It was one location I didn't get changed before posting after making several attempts to get the prepare() to trigger correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Call to a member function prepare() on null` means that you tried to call a method on something that was undefined.

`$dbh` is not a PDO object.  `$dbConn` is your object.

```
$dbConn = DBClass::dbConnect();
// snip
$pstmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM vfs WHERE url = :url || short_url = :url");
```

Comment: Updated code to $dbConn->prepare() with no difference for a result. That was my bad, experimenting on several things and forgot to change that one location back..

Comment: The same error message appears. Hence why I wonder if the host has somehow prevented dbo->prepare() from functioning.

Comment: Perhaps do a `var_dump($dbConn)` just before the prepare to make sure `$dbConn` is still what we think it is.  The error message is saying that it isn't what we think it is.

Comment: Thanks for stepping through this with me. I've been uploading FTP and it seems something was cached in my client and not updating the server correctly. When I took your `var_dump($dbConn)` I uploaded file the server file manager and I'm now getting the expected results. Really appreciate your help @TimMorton..

Comment: glad to help :)